# Pricing a bond with variable strike collar with QuantLibXL

Tags: quantlib, floating-rate

I am trying to price a floating rate bond with a capped and floored interest rate.
The strikes of the caps and floors vary, but are known in advance.

I am trying to do this with QuantLibXL, but I am having trouble at every step. I would appreciate if you could just comment on my general approach, then I will try to fill the gaps.

My current approach is to use `qlFloatingRateBond` and pass it a range of strikes (one for each coupon) for both `Caps` and `Floors` arguments. Then I imagine I have to use `qlBlackCapFloorEngine` as pricing engine, is that right?

The latter needs then an `OptionletVolatilityStructure`, which I strip from a swaption vol cube using `qlOptionletStripper1`. <strike>The issue I have here is that AFAIK Bloomberg’s VCUB returns only Cap volatilities for each option tenor relative to the ATM strike, while `qlOptionletStripper1` wants "absolute" ones. What do you suggest here?</strike> *Update: The volatilities returned are in fact **not** relative to the ATM strike, but absolute.*

Thank you very much.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Answering my own question:

- use `qlFloatingRateBond` and pass it a range of strikes (one for each coupon) for both Caps and Floors arguments
- use `BondEngine` as pricing engine
- use `IborCouponPricer` with Type argument equal to "IborByBlack" as coupon pricer - This pricer also takes an `OptionletVolatilitySurface` as input
- the `OptionletVolatilitySurface` can be created by an `OptionletStripper1` from a `CapFloorVolTermSurface`, (NB. We have to use the `StrippedOptionletAdapter` to mold the `OptionletStripper1` object into an `OptionletVolatilitySurface`)
- create a `CapFloorVolTermSurface` with data, e.g., from ICAP (on Bloomberg terminals, these can be found in `VOLS`), making sure that the IborIndex argument has the same tenor as the input data, i.e., 1Y